# Блок формы по центру

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Необходимо размещать блок формы по центру экрана, если он влазит, а если он не влазит, то добавлять скролл, но чтоб он был тоже по центру относительно области всей страницы. Подскажите пожалуйста, может кто сталкивался с таким...Что-то вроде центрирования попапа. `position: absolute` не подходит. Высота формы может меняться в зависимости от контента внутри. Может есть способ какой-то реализовать это с помощью `flexbox`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.mainSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.formBlock {
  padding: 25px 50px;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: auto;
}

.formBlock .inputGroup {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.formBlock .inputGroup input {
  width: 100%;
}

.formBlock button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="mainSection">
  <div class="formBlock">
    <form>
      <div class="inputGroup">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>

      <div class="inputGroup">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>

      <div class="inputGroup">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>

      <div class="inputGroup">
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы центрировать по центру экрана, родительский блок должен иметь высоту экрана. Добавление свойства height к .mainSection должно решить Вашу проблему

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.mainSection {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.formBlock {
  padding: 25px 50px;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: auto;
}

.formBlock .inputGroup {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.formBlock .inputGroup input {
  width: 100%;
}

.formBlock button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="mainSection">
  <div class="formBlock">
    <form>
      <div class="inputGroup">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>

      <div class="inputGroup">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>

      <div class="inputGroup">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="inputGroup">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="inputGroup">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="inputGroup">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="inputGroup">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>

      <div class="inputGroup">
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>

</section>
```